# After applied https getting issue in admin panel

Tags: cakephp

I have some issue in admin panel.
I provided https on admin panel. Certificate is already installed on site.
I wrote following code.

```
if($_server[HTTP_Host]=='www.test.com'){
    if($this->action['prefix']=='admin'){
        $this->SSL->force();
    }
}
```

This code is in looping it is not proceeding to next page.

Comment: what version of Cake are you using? Have you looked at this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#SecurityComponent::requireSecure

Comment: You are always NOT checking the scheme, but the domain. how can this possibly not loop-redirect? :)

Comment: @joshua.paling cakephp 2.3

Comment: @mark I think the point he's making is that $this->SSL->force(); should not redirect if the current request is already over SSL

Comment: If he followed the book (which it looks like), then the assumption is clearly flawed: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html The usage of request handler would be appropriate here instead of always calling this method.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the loop yourself - thus removing the loop resolves your issue.

You have two options:

Follow the book on how to properly use RequestHandler here to only trigger the redirect method as a "blackhole callback" (which does not get invoked when its already ssl).
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#usage

Create your own method (which you did) that internally checks the protocol and then decides whether the redirect is required. You are missing this vital check on the server var `HTTPS` or something equivalent here.

I would go with the first option and let Cake take care of it. Work with the framework, not against it.